# Amazon Pay permissions not showing

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, amazon-pay

I have a skill which utilizes Amazon pay and other permissions (user's mobile number email and name, device address, alexa notifications,Skills Personalization).

All permission are visible on the Alexa app/web interface but Amazon pay isn't and on the developer portal all permissions are toggled. Is this a bug or I am missing something ?

Comment: I have the same issue. is it solved?

Answer (score 2):

this sounds to me like you possibly did not link your Amazon Pay merchant account to the skill. Please check here for guidance on required steps:

https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/amazon-pay-alexa/integrate-skill-with-amazon-pay-v2.html#link-your-skill-with-your-amazon-payments-account-in-seller-central

There is some caching in place. It might take a while for the permission to show up, once you linked the skill to your merchant account. I'm unfortunately not aware of the cache eviction time.
Daniel

Comment: in fact i have followed all the steps and i link the skill to the merchant account and it still not working.

Comment: Just to rule out any potential caching that is in place - are you still seeing the issue?

Which locales are you using in your skill and from which region is your Amazon Pay merchant account?

Comment: my skill locale: fr-FR
my Amazon Pay merchant account on europe seller center

Comment: Is there a way how I could get in touch with you to deep dive this? LinkedIn, email or any other way? I'd love to help you resolve this.

Comment: yeah sure 
this is my linkedin account: https://www.linkedin.com/in/oumayma-meddeb/